# wrong result shown in converting float to integer in pd

Tags: pandas, integer

[image: pandas]

hi i want to ask why i convert to int but the result still remain as float64

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html), the method returns a new DataFrame. This means that you want to store the result in the variable `df_cleaned` to override the previous value:

```
df_cleaned = df_cleaned.convert_dtypes(convert_integer=True)
```